# How can I make Inno Setup ignore empty directories?

Tags: inno-setup

My Inno Setup script includes a directory:

```
[Files]
...
Source: C:\MyProg\Tools\*.*; Destdir: {app}\Tools
...
```

But sometimes this directory is empty and in that case Inno Setup stops with an error "No files matching ...".

My current workaround is adding an empty dummy file to that directory.

Can I make Inno Setup ignore this directory if it is empty?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Did you try the `skipifsourcedoesntexist` flag?

```
[Files]
...
Source: C:\MyProg\Tools\*.*; Destdir: {app}\Tools; Flags: skipifsourcedoesntexist 
...
```

Comment: All these years I'm using Inno Setup but I've never come across that flag :)

Comment: Wow. This will certainly make my life easier; got a project with generated folders that may or may not exist depending on common files split off into them. Thanks!

Comment: On a related note, just "\*" works. Doesn't need to be "\*.\*".

Comment: @Nyerguds Actually, while they are similar, * and *.* are not the same. * will capture all files. *.* will only capture files with extensions.

Comment: @amalgamate Did you actually test that? Because the file filter code used by the .net framework literally just doesn't filter at all from the moment it sees the "\*.\*" filter, making me suspect that might be a general Windows OS rule. Anyway, all the more reason to use plain \*, I'd say. (btw, you can use "\*.\*" in comments here by escaping the \* with "\")

Comment: @Nyerguds oops Did not see that escape problem. sorry... The meaning is not the same, regardless of the correctness of the results. Seems like you did not test it either. Perhaps I'll test it later. So to clarify, you mean to say that inno setup will not make a distinction between \* and  \*.\* . It is possible that would have some subtle impact on what the op is trying to do. That would mean that we all should always only use \* and not \*.\* , I do think I saw \*.\* in the inno-setup documentation...

Comment: To follow that further, that would mean I couldn't ask for \*.dll, for example? (That's a earnest question not rhetorical) If so, that would seem wrong to me and worth fixing.

Comment: @amalgamate: Haven't had the chance to test, but what I mean to say is mostly that if Inno Setup uses the standard Windows file filter functions, it won't even depend on Inno itself, no matter their intent. As for your "\*.dll", that should function perfectly. The code I saw (from the .net framework internals) actually made exceptions specifically and only on "\*.\*" and "\*", as speed optimization to avoid unnecessary filtering.

Comment: @Nyerguds 
 
 
Don't bother testing. I see what you mean now. I have clearly learned something there. Thanks.